# Revert local changes in fossil

Tags: version-control, fossil

How do I clean/revert/undo local, un-commited changes in a *single* source file with Fossil?

The [clean](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/help?cmd=clean) command looks to me like it should do the trick, but no, the local changes are still there.  I am looking for the same effect as "git checkout filename.c" would have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
fossil revert <filename>
```

.

```
>fossil help revert
Usage: fossil revert ?-r REVISION? ?FILE ...?

Revert to the current repository version of FILE, or to
the version associated with baseline REVISION if the -r flag
appears.

If FILE was part of a rename operation, both the original file
and the renamed file are reverted.

Revert all files if no file name is provided.

If a file is reverted accidently, it can be restored using
the "fossil undo" command.

Options:
  -r REVISION    revert given FILE(s) back to given REVISION

See also: redo, undo, update
```

Comment: Oh, scary to read "Revert all files if no file name is provided" until "If a file is reverted accidently, it can be restored". :-)

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys, it saved my bacon tonight!